Suppress GLib-GIO-WARNING originating from Weasyprint/GTK3
I'm using Weasyprint in Python to generate PDF files from HTML files.
After a recent system update of my Windows machine, I started to observe waring log messages printed on the console such as this one:

(process:41316): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 10:36:44.529: Unexpectedly, UWP
app Microsoft.OutlookForWindows_1.2024.403.300_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe' (AUMId Microsoft.OutlookForWindows_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.OutlookforWindows')
supports 4 extensions but has no verbs

This is apparently coming from the GLib library of GTK3 on which Weasyprint relies on to produce the PDF files.
My application is behaving as expected, except for those warning messages.
I would like to know if there are ways to control the logging level of GLib from Weasyprint in Python to suppress those messages.
Note:
It seems that those messages originate from a sub-process, so the following trick didn't work in this case:
old_stdout = sys.stdout # backup current stdout
sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, "w")

suspect_function()

sys.stdout = old_stdout # reset old stdout 


I'd love an answer to this. I keep checking back here every few weeks hoping someone answered.

@JosephLong The way I got around this while waiting for a better option is by wrapping my function into an application using PyInstaller. I then call the resulting .exe with subprocess.run from my Python code and I ignore stdout.
